# How to set Dynamic meta title for cms page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

How to set different meta title for the same page. I am getting meta title data based on the page url (?id=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plugin

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Block\Page">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Cms_Block_PagePlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Cms\Block\PagePlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Cms/Block/PagePlugin.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Cms\Block;

use Magento\Cms\Block\Page as PageBlock;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config as PageConfig;

class PagePlugin
{
    protected PageConfig $pageConfig;

    public function __construct(PageConfig $pageConfig)
    {
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
    }

    public function afterSetLayout(PageBlock $subject, PageBlock $result, LayoutInterface $layout): PageBlock
    {
        // objects
        $request = $subject->getRequest();
        $page    = $subject->getPage();

        // example how to update
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set('ACME ' . $page->getTitle());
        $this->pageConfig->setKeywords('ACME ' . $page->getMetaKeywords());
        $this->pageConfig->setDescription('ACME ' . $page->getMetaDescription());

        return $result;
    }
}
```