# How to set meta title dynamically for specific category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

I want to set meta title dynamically for specific category only and i getting meta title information based on url id(?id=1).
events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="catalog_category_load_after">
    <observer instance="StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\CategoryLoadAfter" 
              name="stackexchange_magento_observer_frontend_catalog_category_load_after"
    />
</event>
```

observer

```
public function execute(
\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
  $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
  $metaTitle = $category->getName() ." - xxx.club";
  $metaDesc = "Place order for " .$category->getName() . " with us and get huge sales and discount!";
  if ($category instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category) {
  //$oldMetaTitle = $category->getMetaTitle();
  $oldMetaDesc = $category->getMetaDesc();
  //$category->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);
  $category->setMetaDescription($metaDesc);
 }
}
```

I followed above solution. But its applying for all the categories in website.

Any help can be appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the similar logic like described in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/357049/91782

You need to create plugin for `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View` and modify metadata on `afterSetLayout`.

Don't forget to change `$subject`, `$result` and return type to `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View`

```
// category object is
$category = $subject->getCurrentCategory();
if ($category) {
    // update metadata

    // in original logic also present following
    $pageMainTitle = $layout->getBlock('page.main.title');
    if ($pageMainTitle) {
        $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($category->getName());
    }
}
```

Alternative way is use `beforeSetLayout` instead of `afterSetLayout` and try to update category data. Signature:

```
    public function beforeSetLayout(CategoryBlock $subject, LayoutInterface $layout): array
    {
        $category = $subject->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $metaDesc = "Place order for " .$category->getName() . " with us and get huge sales and discount!";
            $category->setMetaDescription($metaDesc);
            // ...
        }

        return [$layout];
    }
```

I suggest to use `afterSetLayout` and update data into page config instead of replace category data runtime.